# Scoping data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My parent component has two separate event handlers which collect data from child components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  ...

  handleClick(data1){
    console.log(data1);

  }

  handleSubmit(data2){
    console.log(data);
    method(data1, data2)
  }

}
```

Inside my handleSubmit handler I want to call the a method to post both of the data objects. How do I access data1 inside of the data2 handler?

Answer (score 1):

When making a React class and defining methods just as you would use `this.setState({})` if you would like to access a predefined method (handleClick) you can simply write `this.handleClick`. The `this` keyword refers to the class in this context.

```
 class MyCompnonent extends React.Component{

handleClick(data){
    this.setState({
     data1: data
    });
    console.log(data1);

 }

  handleSubmit(data2){
    console.log(data);
    this.method(this.state.data1, data2);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in order to ensure that the calls to `this.state.data1` and `this.setState` will have the correct scope of `this` within the handler definition when called, you have to ensure that your event handlers are correct bound to the parent MyComponent class, eg: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data values are passed via another component (parent) so it's passed through **props** and can be accessed via `this.props` in case their values won't be changed, otherwise you may need to save your data values `data1` and `data2` via the **component state** to be something like the follow:

```
handleClick(data1){
   this.setState({data1});
 }

 handleSubmit(data2){
   this.setState({data2});
   method(this.state.data1, this.state.data2)
 }
```